# Pandas Dataframe to Numpy Array with '\t' delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i am trying to load some data that is several thousand rows and 4 columns, where each column is separated by a tab space, and turn every item of every row into an int datatype.

when i create the dataframe like this:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv('filename', sep='\t')
```

i get a output where each row looks like this:

```
col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4
```

i then need to transform this into a numpy array so i do this:

```
arr_data = np.array(my_data)
```

this is my output now:

```
array([['col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4'],
       ['col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4'],
       ['col1\tcol2\tcol3\tcol4'], 
       .....
       .....
```

so basically now each row is a string.
what i'd like to do is turn everything into an `int`, instead of `string` but when i try to to do this:

```
arr_data = np.array(my_data, dtype=int)
```

i get a `ValueError`

do i need to write a nested for loop to go through every row, and then every column in every row to make each item into an `int`??

edit:
i've also just noticed that when i create the dataframe the data is of shape `(rows, 1)` instead of `(rows, 4)`, which i guess means the `delimiter` didn't work?
here's the first few rows:

```
1   1   5   874965758
1   2   3   876893171
1   3   4   878542960
1   4   3   876893119
1   5   3   889751712
1   7   4   875071561
```

thanks

Comment: What you say is somewhat hard to believe. Could you include the first couple of rows of the file?

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots, but the _actual_ data. Screenshots cannot be copied, if necessary. I suspect that your columns are space-separated. Check is setting the separator to `'\s+'` helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns are not TAB-separated. They are space-separated. Use `sep='\s+'` to parse them. This separator incidentally also covers tabs.

Comment: THANK YOU. will accept as correct answer as soon as SO allows. thank you

Comment: may i ask how you figured this out by just looking at the data?

Comment: That was the only plausible explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the flag `delim_whitespace`

```
my_data = pd.read_csv('filename', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: thank you. this worked as well. is there any difference between `delim_whitespace=True` and using the `sep = \s+`  argument?

Comment: @JessiAbrams it is the same thing, but `delim_whitespace=True` is easily readable/maintainable while `sep='\s+'` is not.